# Error while decoding a byte array to base64 which contains characters like '-' and '_'

Tags: java, encoding, base64, decode

I am trying to base64 decode a byte array and everything is running fine as long as my byte array does not contain any characters like '-'or '_'. But whenever the byte array contains '-' I get an exception as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
```

and when the byte array contains'_', the exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5f
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
```

i.e. a difference of code after character 2d to 5f.
What are these codes. And how can i decode any value irrespective of these characters in my code?

Here is my code snippet:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.*;
...

public class BasicSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      byte[] encoded = res.getBytes("s_id");
      System.out.printf("\nInside Byte %s\n",new String(encoded) );
      try {
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);

        System.out.printf("\nDecoded Byte %s\n",new String(decoded, "UTF-8") );
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

Replace `'-'` with `'+'` and `'_'` with `'/'` as in the line below

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/'));
```

### Rationale

There's **Base64** encoding and there's **Base64url** encoding. They're exactly the same, except for the two character replacements indicated above.

Look at Table 1 and Table 2 in [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648):

```
                Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet

 Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
     0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
     1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
     2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
     3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
     4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
     5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
     6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
     7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
     8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
     9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
    10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
    11 L            28 c            45 t            62 +
    12 M            29 d            46 u            63 /
    13 N            30 e            47 v
    14 O            31 f            48 w         (pad) =
    15 P            32 g            49 x
    16 Q            33 h            50 y

[...]

                Table 2: The "URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet

 Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
     0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
     1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
     2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
     3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
     4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
     5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
     6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
     7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
     8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
     9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
    10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
    11 L            28 c            45 t            62 - (minus)
    12 M            29 d            46 u            63 _
    13 N            30 e            47 v           (underline)
    14 O            31 f            48 w
    15 P            32 g            49 x
    16 Q            33 h            50 y         (pad) =
```

Here's another quote from the RFC:

> This encoding may be referred to as "base64url".  This encoding
> should not be regarded as the same as the "base64" encoding and
> should not be referred to as only "base64".  Unless clarified
> otherwise, "base64" refers to the base 64 in the previous section.
> This encoding is technically identical to the previous one, except
> for the 62:nd and 63:rd alphabet character, as indicated in Table 2.

Answer (score 2):

As per [RFC 2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), Table 1: The Base64 Alphabet neither `-` nor `_` are part of alphabet. Only characters present in the alphabet are used by the `Base64` decoder, you can't just decode arbitrary characters.

```
                Table 1: The Base64 Alphabet

 Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
     0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
     1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
     2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
     3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
     4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
     5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
     6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
     7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
     8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
     9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
    10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
    11 L            28 c            45 t            62 +
    12 M            29 d            46 u            63 /
    13 N            30 e            47 v
    14 O            31 f            48 w         (pad) =
    15 P            32 g            49 x
    16 Q            33 h            50 y
```

As Roland Illig pointed out, you might be dealing with URL friendly Base 64 variant where `_` replaces `+` and `-` replaces `/`. In this case it might be sufficient to revert the change before decoding:

```
String raw = new String(res.getBytes("s_id"));
String encoded = raw.replace("_", "+").replace("-", "/");
String decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

However there is no telling how the data is actually encoded without seeing the server-side encoding code.

Comment: actually I am getting this encoded data from the server and I just have to decode it for some purpose.So I have no control over the presence of these values in the ecoded byte array. Can you please suggest what is the best possible thing to do in order to successfully decode this?

Comment: Then you are either are not using `Base64` on the server to encode the data or you are reading it wrong. Figure out how exactly the data is encoded on the server and use the correct decoder.

Comment: Your answer should mention the "URL-friendly" variant of Base64, which uses _ and - instead of + and /.